# Proxmox problems with disks?? Keep getting different exit codes

Tags: linux, proxmox

I recently bought a server. This server has 2x 4core xeon and 28gb ram. I installed Proxmox on it and when I try to make a directory it keeps spitting out exit codes.

[These are the exit codes!](https://pastebin.com/P0yfmngC)

Can some one explain what I am doing wrong because I do not understand what is going on here. I have tried serveral disks and it gives me exit code 2, 3 or 4. Most recent one is 3! Greetings Bartjuuh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to re-initialize your disks with a proper configuration.

Something concrete to research:

2x4 core Xeons sound like a pretty old server. Does the server or its disk controller support the disks you're using and their format?